# How to add String variable or a --i:0 property on inline style ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, inline-styles

```
<li style="--i: 0">
        <a href=""><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></a>
      </li>
      <li style="--i: 1">
        <a href=""><ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon></a>
      </li>
      <li style="--i: 2">
        <a href=""><ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon></a>
      </li>
      <li style="--i: 3">
        <a href=""><ion-icon name="mail-outline"></ion-icon></a>
      </li>
      <li style="--i: 4">
        <a href=""><ion-icon name="key-outline"></ion-icon></a>
      </li>
      <li style="--i: 5">
        <a href=""><ion-icon name="videocam-outline"></ion-icon></a>
      </li>
      <li style="--i: 6">
        <a href=""><ion-icon name="game-controller-outline"></ion-icon></a>
      </li>
      <li style="--i: 7">
        <a href=""><ion-icon name="camera-outline"></ion-icon></a>
      </li>
```

**This is my HTML file with style="--i:0" to --i:7 property**

```
  <li style={--i: 0}>
          <i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </li>
```

**This is the code from ReacJS giving a --i:0 to inline style. And getting an error of "Style prop value must be an object". Can someone help me to apply what I did on the HTML file example on React inline style?**

Comment: What 'style' are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just to pass --i: 0 to --i: 7 to my inline style={} on reactjs sir to pass it to my CSS rotation style.

`transform: rotate(calc(360deg / 8 * var(--i)))`

Answer (score 0):

In react to write styles directly, you have to do this => `<li style={{ ...properties  }}></li>`

I don't know if u can access custom variables from react like that, what u can do is this.

```
<li style={`--i=${YOUR_VALUE}`}></li>
```

I hope I have been able to help you

Comment: There is no error Sir Juan, but I can't display it to my DOM. Thanks for the help btw

Answer (score 0):

To achieve `transform: rotate(calc(360deg / 8 * var(--i)))` in style, try

```
{let s = rotate(calc(360deg / 8 * var(--i))) // assume i has some value}
<li style={{transform: s }}></li>
```

Comment: Still not displaying on my DOM. Thank you Mulli. I fix it by returning an HTML element and store it on a const element = ' <li style={--i: 0}>
          <i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </li>'