# How to use a variable or a --i:0 property on inline style ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

This question was asked before but was never fully answered in [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72412584/how-to-add-string-variable-or-a-i0-property-on-inline-style-reactjs)The variables are probably the most important part of this code as I want to be able to use them in multiple CSS functions to animate them with hover effects. I have the html equivalent which is this

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card" style="--i:-1" ></div>
        <div class="card" style="--i:0"></div>
        <div class="card" style="--i:1"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    

export default Project
```

I want my code to be able to do the same thing in a React inline style JSX/JS file. So far all I've come to is this:

```
import './project.css';
const numbers = [-1,0,1]
var r = document.querySelector(':root');
const Project = () => {
    return( 
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div className="container">
      {numbers.map((num) => (<div key={num} className="card" {...r.style.setProperty('--i', -1)}></div>))}

      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    )
}

export default Project
```

however this unfortunately only uses the last value in the list (being 1) and uses this value for all functions in the CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```
       <body>
        <div className="container">
          {numbers.map((num) => (
            <div key={num} className="card" style={{ "--i": num }}></div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link you posted, I think what you're trying to achieve is setting a CSS variable in the `style` prop for a JSX Element.

You can do so like this:

```
const SomeComponent = () => (
  <div 
    style={{
      "--i": -1
    }}
  >
    <div
      style={{
        // rotate with some arbitrary calculation using the `--i` CSS variable
        transform: "rotate(calc(360deg / 8 * (var(--i) - 10)))",
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        backgroundColor: "magenta"
      }}
    />
  </div>
)
```

I created a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-ans-inline-css-var-react-r9xmlt?file=/src/App.tsx) that shows this in action where the value for `--i` comes from some array of whatever length. The `--i` value is then used as a part of the background color and transform CSS props for a div. The screenshot below shows the resulting UI for an array of 20.

Note: This example uses [Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/) so you won't be able to `copy/paste` from the Code Sandbox. You will have to change the `sx` prop to `style` if you want to reuse the code.

Hope this helps!

[image]